# Open Telemetry propagator instantiation vs global

Tags: rust, open-telemetry

I've been looking at some Open Telemetry sample code and noticed an asymmetry between what is done on the client side and server side with regard to the propagator.

```rust
// client side
global::get_text_map_propagator(|propagator| {
    propagator.inject_context(&cx, &mut trace)
});
```

```rust
// server side
let response_propagator = TraceContextResponsePropagator::new();
response_propagator.inject_context(&cx, &mut trace);
```

Is there any reason for why the client would grab the propagator from a global, whereas the server constructs a fresh propagator? Is this a convention, or just a quirk of the examples I've seen?